# How many synapses per node do I need?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

I want to implement a perceptron network and I have a little problem. The first implementation will be very simple. Just three layers, input, one hidden and the output layer. My problem is that how many synapses is optimal for a hidden node beetwen the input and hidden layer? I think not too economical if every node join to every input nodes.

Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Usually every input is connected to every hidden node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In very general setting you plug in every single node of a given layer with every node in the next one. This is called "fully connected layer". Obviously this is not the only option, and with more advanced approaches you will find much more sparse connectomes, like receptive fields, cvonolutional layers etc. For a simple experiments, starting with fully connected layers is preferable, as other connection strategies usually assume something about your data (like spatial-temporal relations of inputs), while fully connected layer is the agnostic, generic approach.